# Spark dies with NullPointerException UTF8String.getBaseObject() "input" is null

Tags: java, apache-spark

Spark 3.3.0 is breaking all over the place with a simple pipeline on Windows 10 using Java 17. Now it's giving me this:

```
[ERROR] Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 5) (xps-13-9310 executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.getBaseObject()" because "input" is null
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here's the full previous stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 5)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.getBaseObject()" because "input" is null
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[WARN] Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 5) (xps-13-9310 executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.getBaseObject()" because "input" is null
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have no idea where to start looking for a workaround, as this appears to be deep in the bowels of Spark. (I can't help but say that this along with [Spark NullPointerException: Cannot invoke invalidateSerializedMapOutputStatusCache() because "shuffleStatus" is null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73732970) is not giving me much confidence in Spark. Nobody seems to have answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was apparently causing this. I have a UDF that returns several columns using:

```java
StructType schema = createStructType(List.of(… createStructField("bar", StringType, false)));
UserDefinedFunction foobarUdf = udf((String foo) -> {
  …
}, schema).asNondeterministic();
```

Note that I specify `false` for `bar`'s nullability. It turns out that `foobarUdf` actually returns `null` for `bar` sometimes. In the relational database world, I would expect that if my integrity constraint wasn't met, the database would say, "you put `null` in `bar`, but `bar` is not nullable". Spark, however, hits a {{NullPointerException}} and has a nervous breakdown.

I've filed bug report [SPARK-40541](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-40541).